# Django Python - How to display informations from different tables in one HTML template

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, templates

I have a MySQL database containing 4 tables.
Those tables have 4 corresponding classes in my models.py file (in my Django app).
I have defined some views in the views.py file and made some HTML templates but each template can communicate only with 1 view (and I think it has to be like this).
But I would like to display on a html template informations coming from different tables (classes from models.py).

For example:
I have a template "about.html" like this:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'pdbapp/stat_style.css' %}" />

<body class="news">
  <header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="/pdbapp/home/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="info PDB"><a href="/pdbapp/pdbinfo/">Infos</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a class="active" href="/pdbapp/about/">About</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

<h1>About Us</h1>

<h2>Project members</h2>

{% if namelist %}
    <ul>
    {% for i in namelist %}
        <li><a href="/pdbapp/pdbinfo/{{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No informations available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

And I would like to display in my HTML template the number of entries in the MySQL tables "PDB" and "struct_sec" (see below):

```
CREATE TABLE PDB(
    id_PDB_chain CHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    id_PDB CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    chaine VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    header VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    sequence_Proteine TEXT NOT NULL,
    start_seq INT NOT NULL,
    taille_Proteine INT NOT NULL,
    resolution_PDB FLOAT NOT NULL,
    meth_Res VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (meth_Res)
    REFERENCES methodes_res(meth_Res)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE struct_sec(
    id_struct_sec INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    start_pred INT NOT NULL,
    structure_Predite TEXT NOT NULL,
    nombre_PPII INT NOT NULL,
    pourcentage_PPII FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    angle_phi TEXT NOT NULL,
    angle_psi TEXT NOT NULL,
    id_PDB_chain CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    nom_Analyse VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_PDB_chain)
    REFERENCES PDB(id_PDB_chain)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (nom_Analyse)
    REFERENCES methodes_analyse(nom_Analyse)
    ON DELETE CASCADE 
);
```

Here are the corresponding class in the file "models.py":

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Pdb(models.Model):
    id_pdb_chain = models.CharField(db_column='id_PDB_chain', primary_key=True, max_length=5)  # Field name made lowercase.
    id_pdb = models.CharField(db_column='id_PDB', max_length=4)  # Field name made lowercase.
    chaine = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    header = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sequence_proteine = models.TextField(db_column='sequence_Proteine')  # Field name made lowercase.
    start_seq = models.IntegerField()
    taille_proteine = models.IntegerField(db_column='taille_Proteine')  # Field name made lowercase.
    resolution_pdb = models.FloatField(db_column='resolution_PDB')  # Field name made lowercase.
    meth_res = models.ForeignKey('MethodesRes', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='meth_Res')  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id_pdb

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'PDB'

class StructSec(models.Model):
    id_struct_sec = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    start_pred = models.IntegerField()
    structure_predite = models.TextField(db_column='structure_Predite')  # Field name made lowercase.
    nombre_ppii = models.IntegerField(db_column='nombre_PPII')  # Field name made lowercase.
    pourcentage_ppii = models.FloatField(db_column='pourcentage_PPII')  # Field name made lowercase.
    angle_phi = models.TextField()
    angle_psi = models.TextField()
    id_pdb_chain = models.ForeignKey(Pdb, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_PDB_chain')  # Field name made lowercase.
    nom_analyse = models.ForeignKey(MethodesAnalyse, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='nom_Analyse')  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id_pdb_chain)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'struct_sec'
```

How should I do this.
I am a very beginner in Django, please believe that I really tried to understand what has already been explained on the web about this unsuccessfully.

Comment: You can query all of your tables in single view and then pass data to template.

Answer (score 5):

Your view should look like this:

```
def detail(request, poll_id):
    pdbs = Pdb.objects.all()
    structSecs = StructSec.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'pdbs': pdbs, 'structSecs': structSecs})
```

Then in template:

```
{% for pdb in pdbs %}
    {{pdb.header}} 
{% endfor %}

{% for structSec in structSecs %}
    {{structSecs.structure_predite}} 
{% endfor %}
```

More: [queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/) and [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/) and [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/)

Comment: I think that if I write this, my html page will display a list of Pdb entries and then a list of StructSec entries, but it is not counting entries as I would like.

is there anything like for example : 
pdbs = Pdb.objects.all().count()
Which could count entries in the table Pdb ? 
Thanks anyway for the tips to display all informations on the same template I am going to try that.

Comment: This will work pdbs = Pdb.objects.count() or  pdbs = Pdb.objects.filter(header='something').count(). Can you mark as accepted?

Comment: And it doesn't work. 

I corrected the {{structSecs.structure_predite}} into {{structSec.structure_predite}}  (remove the "s")

But there is still this error : 
"about() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

I think django doesn't understand what poll_id is.
How to solve this problem ?